# Exactly how unreliable is Akka remote messaging?

Tags: akka

I'm involved in the design of an application that seems like a good fit for Akka actors. In this system, not all messages would need to be reliably delivered. In some cases, the consequences of a lost message would be relatively minor, in other cases, the consequences would be somewhat serious.

I'm aware from the Akka documentation that remote messaging is not reliable, and that there are patterns to provide reliable messaging.

However, in some cases, there are other ways we could deal with delivery failure, especially if it's not a common occurence. I'd like to get an idea of how unreliable message delivery is in practice, with typical config and the standard transports.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

- TCP transport is as reliable as the underlying TCP connection
- TCP transport will sometimes fail spuriously, by design
- TCP transport will drop messages under heavy load
- TCP transport will retry messages on connection failure
- UDP transport is as reliable as UDP message delivery
- UDP transport will discard messages that arrive out-of-order
- UDP transport will retry messages up to a configured limit
- Message delivery failure will almost always trigger `Terminated` messages on watched actors

If it depends on config, what does it depend on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- TCP transport is as reliable as the underlying TCP connection

  Yes
- TCP transport will sometimes fail spuriously, by design

  No
- TCP transport will drop messages under heavy load

  No
- TCP transport will retry messages on connection failure

  Akka 2.2.3 tried to do that, but that feature was removed in 2.3.0-RC1 because it caused more confusion than it helped.
- Message delivery failure will almost always trigger Terminated messages on watched actors

  Terminated is related to watch of actor, and not to delivery failure.
  For example messages may be lost if you have a transient network glitch, but if it is short enough it will not trigger Terminated.